# error with javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser

Tags: android, xml, saxparser

I'm trying call a external xml and I have a something errors.

**Error**

> 06-02 04:32:21.085    1658-1658/com.golftipp E/Ideas4All﹕ Error
>       android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
>               at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1145)
>               at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:385)
>               at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
>               at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
>               at com.android.okhttp.internal.Dns$1.getAllByName(Dns.java:28)
>               at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:216)
>               at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:122)
>               at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:292)
>               at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:255)
>               at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:206)
>               at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:345)
>               at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:296)
>               at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:179)
>               at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:470)
>               at com.golftipp.IntroduceCodigo.loadCategories(IntroduceCodigo.java:111)
>               at com.golftipp.IntroduceCodigo.irFormularioReserva(IntroduceCodigo.java:67)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>               at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3818)
>               at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
>               at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
>               at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
>               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
>               at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

**Code**

```
private Vector<datos_codigos> categories;
private String categories_url = "http://www.url.com/beta.xml";

public void loadCategories() {

    try {

        // Url del archivo XML
        URL url = new URL(categories_url);

        SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();

        XMLReader xr = sp.getXMLReader();
        // Utilizamos nuestro propio parseador (CategoryHandler)
        xmlSax myExampleHandler = new xmlSax();
        xr.setContentHandler(myExampleHandler);

        InputSource is = new InputSource(url.openStream());
        // Le indicamos la codificación para evitar errores
        is.setEncoding("UTF-8");
        xr.parse(is);

        // Asignamos al vector categories los datos parseados
        categories = myExampleHandler.getParsedData();
        System.out.println(myExampleHandler.getParsedData());


    } catch (Exception e) {
        // Ha ocurrido algún error
        Log.e("Ideas4All", "Error", e);
    }

}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception

Comment: `Error android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException `. network operation on the main ui thread is wrong. use a thread or asynctask

Answer (score 0):

For that you must have to call your method `loadCategories()` in asynch task in `doInBackground` method

because after 4.0 it does't allow to network call on your main ui theread.

```
    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
                @Override
                protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                   loadCategories();
                    return null;
                }
            }.execute();
```

Comment: hey @GovindRathod ...where r u?

Comment: @dipali i am @ here, ohh after so long finally you see here

Comment: @dipali i did ping you at there but not respond you.......

Comment: ab to aa jao...@GovindRathod

Answer (score 0):

```
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
```

Comment: This is not the correct way. You should use AsyncTask